# Javascript resize image to reduce its size before uploading to the server?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, browser

I am making an website that uploads images from the broswer and stores them in the server. However, some images are really heavy and I would like to resize them to have not vary so much in size, mainly to reduce the size of all the images stored.

The client side code on the broswer is below (I am using ReactJS and typescript). I want to use the tools available on the broswer code (don't want to install a library and have to bundle all the javascript code to the client)

I can have them resized on the server, but dont want to use more computing power on the server. Is there a way to resize them on the client to reduce its size?

I don't want to use canvas to redraw them, the main purpose it's to reduce the size.

```
 <input type="file" accept="image/*" onChange={async (ev) => {
                    if (ev && ev.target && ev.target.files) {

                        const formData = new FormData();
                        formData.append("file", ev.target.files[0],  "file.jpg");

                        if(imageHTMLComponent) {
                            const imageReader = new FileReader();
                            imageReader.onload = (ev) => {
                                if( ev.target && typeof ev.target.result === "string") {
                                    test.setAttribute('src', ev.target.result);
                                }
                            }
                            imageReader.readAsDataURL(ev.target.files[0]);

                            const response = await fetch(`https://localhost:8000/test?token=${encodeURI('hello')}&picture=1`, {
                        }

                    }

                Preview of the image:
                <img ref={(ref) => {setImageHTMLComponent(ref)}} />
```

Comment: "I don't want to use canvas to redraw them, the main purpose it's to reduce the size."  Yeah, well, that's how you do it.  Not sure why you're opposed to that.  Also, don't use data URIs... you're forcing a base64 encode of the whole file, not to mention the overhead of injecting it into the DOM the way you're doing it.

Comment: @Brad what do you refer too when talking about "don't use data URIs" ?

Comment: Your code.  `imageReader.readAsDataURL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this link](https://zocada.com/compress-resize-images-javascript-browser/) you can use the native JavaScript and HTML5 Canvas features to resize an image on the client-side. I have not tried the instructions in this tutorial but I have used HTML5 Canvas in the past to make a 2D RPG engine that resized images. This tutorial, however, goes further and explains how to create an image for the purposes that you are asking for. Looking over this tutorial, it also provides alternatives if your native browser doesn't support certain features, like "toBlob".

Comment: Yep, it worked. The only thing is that I had to create a image element with HTML, creating it with javascript Image() won't rezise correctly. 
Edit: The resizing does't shrink the image size